# Debugger going to implicit.rb automatically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging

I installed debugger gem in my gemset

```
<pre>
nikhil@nikhil-K54C:/media/media1/railscode/beasport$ bundle show debugger
/home/nikhil/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@beasport/gems/debugger-1.2.0
</pre>
```

My intention is to use this gem to debug my application by placing "debugger" call in my code so that i can use it to debug application.
However strangely even if i have not put "debugger" call anywhere in my code but still whenever i hit any url to my application (from localhost:3000), debugger starts debugging in file

```
<pre>
/home/nikhil/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@beasport/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb
</pre>
```

here is what i get when i do "list"

```
<pre>

=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2012-11-07 19:11:18] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2012-11-07 19:11:18] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2012-04-20) [i686-linux]
[2012-11-07 19:11:18] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=6602 port=3000
/home/nikhil/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@beasport/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5
default_render unless response_body
(rdb:1) list
[0, 9] in /home/nikhil/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@beasport/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb
   1  module ActionController
   2    module ImplicitRender
   3      def send_action(method, *args)
   4        ret = super
=> 5        default_render unless response_body
   6        ret
   7      end
   8  
   9      def default_render(*args)
(rdb:1) 
</pre>
```

I am using webrick. This is frustrating. When i remove debugger gem from gemfile and do "bundle install" then it works fine but i wont be able to debug my application then.
Again i checked with my other application and there debugger works just fine and do not go to implicit.rb unnecessarily.
Please help

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a question posted last year
and you may no longer need answer, but since I also had the same issue and had to solve it myself, I'm posting what worked for me.

```
 gem uninstall debugger
 gem uninstall debugger-linecache
 gem uninstall debugger-ruby_core_source
```

Then,

```
 gem install debugger
```

Comment: Thanks Quv for efforts ...i had got introduced to "PRY" which is excellent for debugging and solved my problems with the help of that...by the way I have moved to more greener pastures(javascript world) now a days and hardly do ruby ... :)